# Compare date times in java in DAY hh:mm-hh:mm

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, dayofweek

How do we comapare dates and get the remainig available slots in java?

```
Sun 10:00-11:00
Sun 12:00-14:00
Sun 15:00-16:00
```

So how can we get alll the availble time for a day in other than these three slots? how do we compare these dates in java? Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: [Date and Time Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) might be a good place to start

Answer (score 1):

Design a class for an occupied slot. It sounds like you need a `DayOfWeek` field and two `LocalTime` fields. Parse the date-times into such objects: split at the hyphen and use a couple of `DateTimeFormatter`s. Sort your objects. For each pair of adjacent objects, determine if there is a vacant slot between them (also report an error if there’s an overlap). You will also need to decide whether to consider a vacant slot before the first date-time (Sunday from 00:00 to 10:00?) and after the last one.

I am on purpose mentioning classes and an `enum` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It’s nice to work with, I recommend it without hesitation.

**EDIT**: You’ve now had five days for coding your class, so it may be time to share my version for you to compare and for future readers.

```
public class Slot {

    private static Pattern textPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+) ([0-9:]+)-([0-9:]+)");
    private static DateTimeFormatter dayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE");

    public static Slot parse(String text) {
        Matcher textMatcher = textPattern.matcher(text);
        if (textMatcher.matches()) {
            DayOfWeek day = DayOfWeek.from(dayFormatter.parse(textMatcher.group(1)));
            LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse(textMatcher.group(2));
            LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse(textMatcher.group(3));
            return new Slot(day, startTime, endTime);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unparsable slot " + text + ", expected format Sun 12:00-14:00");
        }
    }

    private final DayOfWeek day;
    private final LocalTime startTime;
    private final LocalTime endTime;

    Slot(DayOfWeek day, LocalTime startTime, LocalTime endTime) {
        if (! endTime.isAfter(startTime)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("End time must be after start time");
        }
        this.day = Objects.requireNonNull(day);
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public DayOfWeek getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public LocalTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public LocalTime getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    /** 
     * @param nextSlot
     * @return A new Slot object representing the vacant Slot between this Slot and nextSlot,
     *      or an empty Optional if no gap
     */
    public Optional<Slot> slotBetween(Slot nextSlot) {
        if (! nextSlot.getDay().equals(day)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot compare slots on different days of week");
        }
        if (nextSlot.getStartTime().isBefore(endTime)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: overlap between slots " + this + " and " + nextSlot);
        }
        if (nextSlot.getStartTime().isAfter(endTime)) { // there is a gap
            return Optional.of(new Slot(day, endTime, nextSlot.getStartTime()));
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return dayFormatter.format(day) + ' ' + startTime + '-' + endTime;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils` [Apache DateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) for adding specific hours to the time and use `java.util.Date` for various comparisons. Hope this will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use compareTo method. Definition is that *int* java.util.Date.**compareTo**(**Date** anotherDate). Sample code is below:

```
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.set(2015, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);

    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.set(2016, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);

    Date date1 = cal1.getTime();
    Date date2 = cal2.getTime();

    //Print -1, negative
    System.out.println(date1.compareTo(date2));

    cal1.set(2017, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
    date1 = cal1.getTime();
    //Print 1, positive
    System.out.println(date1.compareTo(date2));

    cal1 = cal2;
    date1 = cal1.getTime();
    //Print 0, equal
    System.out.println(date1.compareTo(date2));
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated `Date` and `Calendar` classes. [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: This Answer uses troublesome old classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.